# Saving error in eclipse - Code clean up failed

Tags: java, eclipse

Facing following message after every save operation.

```
A save participant caused problems.
  The save participant 'Code Clean Up' caused an exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gdt/eclipse/suite/preferences/GdtPreferences. See the error log for details.
```

I do not wants to remove the code clean up action from the preference. Could some one please help me how to resolve the problem.

Comment: The class seems to belong to Google Web Toolkit plugin. Do you have it installed?

Comment: Yes, it has been properly installed

Comment: Eclipse disagrees :). Try uninstalling/reinstalling... Also, try setting preferences for this plugin. Does that work?

Comment: Issue resolved using clean refresh on command line